# How to change the button color onmoveover,onmouseleave in wpf by using triggers or any other events

Tags: c#, wpf, button, triggers

I have developed a WPF Application with some buttons. Now i want to change the color of those buttons onmouseover,onmouseleave,onmouseenter by using triggers or any other events.
Any suggestion plz
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Inside the desired event, you can set the background color like this...

```
// Change the background color of button1 to Blue
button1.Background = Brushes.Blue;
```

You can also set this in a trigger:

```
<!-- Button will change from Blue to Yellow on MouseOver -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

For even more details, check out the **Property Triggers** section of [this](http://www.microsoft.com/belux/msdn/nl/community/columns/gillcleeren/wpf_stylesandtriggers.mspx) article.

Comment: A problem with this solution can be found in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302756/why-is-the-buttons-background-changing
The same issue happened to me -- it would not seem to set the background.