# Disable button mouse over effect

Tags: wpf

I have a wppf button with a background image.

When I mouse over background will be empty and a button is shown.

How can I disable mouse effect?

```
<Button BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Content="Reset" BorderThickness="0"Foreground="White" Focusable="False">
                        <Button.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="button.png" />
                        </Button.Background>
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a trigger of use the Visual State Manager. Please provide all the relevant xaml.

Comment: try this;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302756/why-is-the-buttons-background-changing                                           pro-tip, if you don't have the reputation to comment post a "trival answer" and see what happens.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how I disable the visual mouseover effects on buttons. I left in some of my settings just to get you a feel of how to play with the triggers and stuff, feel free to experiment!

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ImageButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gainsboro" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.25" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

EDIT: Using the "BasedOn" + setting FocusVisualStyle to null (first 2 lines) gets rid of the mouse over effects. Everything else is just examples. I added a border there in order to play with it through a trigger (since I want a custom mouseover effect).

Comment: I don't agree with this post.  The first two lines had zero effect in my application.  I've read elsewhere that you aren't allowed to override the template partially, and that you have to make a full and complete template for it to work.  Unfortunately, I haven't found a working solution yet but the advice in this post definitely did not work for me.

Comment: @shawn1874 - "I've read elsewhere" could benefit from a link or two to explain the potential problems of this approach. Have you tried the full sample instead of just the first two lines, in an empty project that isn't altered by "your application", to see if you still cannot make it work? With 7k views, 12 upvotes and not a single downvote, I am under the impression that this answer does satisfy most.

Answer (score 8):

In the `ControlTemplate` of the `Button` the Background property will be overridden by a trigger.
You can either redo the whole `ControlTemplate` and leave out the Background change or just add the image as content of your `Button` like so to avoid all these complications:

```
<Button.Content>
    <Image Source="button.png" />
</Button.Content>
```

Or if you need the text in there as well:

```
<Button.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="button.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="Reset" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Grid>
</Button.Content>
```

Comment: Cannot use it, because I have Content="Reset".

Comment: you can still do complex layout in there by using panels to combine your image and the textblock with the "Reset" in it