# Silverlight MouseOver

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

It's possible to change the image source of a button control on mouseover?

If it's how it's done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code might help:

```
button1.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(button1_MouseEnter);
button1.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(button1_MouseLeave);

void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    button1.Content = image1;
    //do something
}

void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Trigger for this. You may follow [this](http://learnwpf.com/post/2006/03/06/How-do-I-change-an-items-appearance-on-mouseover-in-WPF.aspx) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/934834/840039) article for the solution

ref:

```
<!-- Button will change from Blue to Yellow on MouseOver -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: The question was for Silverlight, not WPF, and there is no `IsMouseOver` property in Silverlight.