# Changing a button's mouse hover color BASED ON the background color

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been trying to figure out on how to change the button's hover color and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934442/how-to-change-the-button-color-onmoveover-onmouseleave-in-wpf-by-using-triggers):

But this is only half of what I'm trying to achieve. I want to change the hover color based on the current background color. i.e

DEFAULT BUTTON BACKGROUND COLOR: GRAY

I click it and the Button's background color will become red. The hover color should be changed into pink.

I click it again and the Button's background color will become green. The hover color should be changed into light green.

Is this possible in mark up and in code behind? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**XAML:**

```
<Button Content="Color change" Background="{Binding BackGround}" Command="{Binding ButtonPressedCommand}">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="Border" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" 
                                Value="{Binding BackGroundOnHover}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" 
                                Value="{Binding BackGround}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Brush _backGround = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        public Brush BackGround
        {
            get { return _backGround; }
            set
            {
                _backGround = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private Brush _backGroundOnHover;
        public Brush BackGroundOnHover
        {
            get
            {
              if (_backGroundOnHover == null)
                    SetHoverBackGround();
                Debug.WriteLine(((SolidColorBrush)_backGroundOnHover).Color.R);
                return _backGroundOnHover;
            }
            set
            {
                _backGroundOnHover = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand _buttonPressedCommand;

        public RelayCommand ButtonPressedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _buttonPressedCommand ??
                       (_buttonPressedCommand = new RelayCommand(SetBackgroundWhenButtonPressed));
            }
        }

        private void SetBackgroundWhenButtonPressed()
        {
            var color = ((SolidColorBrush)BackGround).Color;
            BackGround = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)(color.R - 5), color.G, color.B));
            SetHoverBackGround();
        }

        private void SetHoverBackGround()
        {
            var color = ((SolidColorBrush)BackGround).Color;
            BackGroundOnHover = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)(255-color.R ), color.G, color.B));
        }


        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Whenever you click it changes background color and simultaneously color when mouse is over.

Answer (score 2):

**Button style purely in XAML.**

First define two `SolidColorBrush` one inherits `color` from another, but the second brush opacity is defined.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBrush" Color="red" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="shadedButtonBrush" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonBrush}, Path=Color}" Opacity="0.5" />


    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="custBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="custBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource shadedButtonBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>



    <Button Background="{StaticResource ButtonBrush}">
        Button
    </Button>
```

If you want change the color of the button just change the color of ButtonBrush and everything automatically adjusts itself.